# List being compressed by VStack

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have several views inside of a VStack inside of a ScrollView.

One of the contained views is a list and it is being compressed by the other views in the VStack such that it is not visible any more.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var detailVM = MovieDetailViewModel()
    
    // Core data
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    var movie: Movie
    
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    init(movie: Movie) {
        self.movie = movie
        detailVM.getMovieDetails(id: movie.id)
        detailVM.getRecommendedMovies(movie: movie.id)
        
        // Stop Scrollview bounce
        UIScrollView.appearance().bounces = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        // Movie poster
        MovieHeroImage(movie: movie)
        
        ScrollView {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                Text(movie.overview)
                    .font(.body)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                MovieInfoRow(movie: movie) // <- This view is being compressed and not visible
                
                
                if detailVM.fetchedMovie?.credits != nil {
                    CastView(cast: (detailVM.fetchedMovie?.credits!.cast)!)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                }
                
                RecommendedMoviesView(movies: detailVM.recommendedMovies)
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct MovieDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieDetailView(movie: Movie.example)
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the view that is being compressed:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovieInfoRow: View {
    
    var movie: Movie
    
    var body: some View {
        List {

            Text("Hello")
            Text("Hello")
            Text("Hello")
            Text("Hello")

        }
    }
}

struct MovieInfoRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovieInfoRow(movie: Movie.example)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would imagine you started with commenting out the views above or below to see which view might be causing it.  Or even start with `MovieHeroImage` to make sure you don't have something in one those views that might be causing it. Also what dose it look like in preview?

Comment: It is scroll-in-scroll conflict (because List has own ScrollView), so when you place List/ScrollView into another ScrollView you have to specify its height (here we talk about vertical) explicitly.